# How do I get the bitwise result of a 64 bit number on 32-bit php

Tags: php

I have two 32-bit unsigned integers in php (the result of crc32() ) and I want to get the bitwise result of these numbers on a 32 bit version of php.

I have tried many experiments, but evidently there is something I am missing about how php handles these numbers and binary data.

Update:

I am looking for something like this:

```
$x = crc32("abc");
$bin = sprintf("%b", $x);

$x2    = crc32("abc2");
$bin2 = sprintf("%b", $x2);

$b = $bin | $bin2;


$result = sprintf("%u",$b);

var_dump($result);
```

That code does not work, but by replacing %b and %u with the right numbers I think it could work

Comment: so where does 64 bit come into this question ?

Comment: ex. 4257153023 | 3825205239

@alnitak - php integers are signed so they can tolerate only 31 bit signed integers

Comment: A bitwise or would be the `|` operator, I believe, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the the [bitwise OR `|`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) instead of the logical one, `||`:

```
$x  = crc32("abc");
$x2 = crc32("abc2");
$b = $x | $x2;              // The integer 2142140882
$result = sprintf('%u',$b); // The string "2142140882"
```

If you want to get a binary string of this result, use [`pack`](http://php.net/pack):

```
$result_binary = pack('N', $b); // Binary format, "\x7f\xae\x79\d2"
```

Comment: what does this have to do with my question?

Comment: @user1122069 Your previous version of the question asked for the `bitwise result`, which I took to mean the `concatenation of the bitwise representations of the two numbers`. Your edit clarified that you meant the `result of a bitwise OR operation`, which is a completely different thing. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks. I was so sure that I had tried it that way before, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $x = crc32("abc");
    printf("%x", $x); echo "(sedecimal)<br>\n";
    printf("%u", $x); echo "(integer)<br>\n";
    printf("%b", $x); echo "(binary)<br>\n";
    $bin = sprintf("%b", $x);
```

Comment: thanks, but I am looking to get the bitwise result of two crc results and then return this to a string of the proper unsigned value.

Are you saying that I can take this binary result and then bitwise it and it will work?